# Typing the values of a static object while leaving its keys type as is

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have the following interface and object:

```js
interface Person {
  name: string;
  lastName?: string;
}

const obj: { [key: string]: Person } = {
  a: { name: 'John' },
  b: { name: 'Jane', lastName: 'Doe' },
}
```

This defines the type of the object such that its keys can be any `string`. But I would like to still be able to infer the keys of the object (as it is static), which, in this case, I can't.

I can do something like this:

```js
type ObjKeys = 'a' | 'b';

const obj: { [key in ObjKeys]: Person } //...
```

But it's verbose.

Is there a short way of saying "here is the type for all the values of this object but leave the keys as defined statically?"

Comment: Where are the keys of the object being defined tho?

Comment: "I can do something like this": that's not valid syntax; presumably you mean `{ [K in ObjKeys]: Person }`

Comment: During the definition of the object. It's static, it will always have the keys `a` and `b`.

Comment: @jcalz Yep, you're right. Fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this purely at the type level; if you [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) the type of `obj` with `{[k: string]: Person}` then the compiler will assume that this is the actual type to use and will not [narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) it to something else based on the assignment of `{a: {...}, b: {...}}`.  Such [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) only occurs for values whose type is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types), and `{[k: string]: Person}` is not a union.

What I usually do in situations like this is to write a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) helper [identity function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_function) from which the compiler can infer the type you're looking for:

```
const asPersonDict = <K extends PropertyKey>(
  o: { [P in K]: Person }) => o;
```

And then you call the helper function instead of annotating the type:

```
const obj = asPersonDict({
  a: { name: 'John' },
  b: { name: 'Jane', lastName: 'Doe' },
});

/* const obj: {
    a: Person;
    b: Person;
} */
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4BQyyIcAthAFzIZhSgDmA3EcgDZy0By5EA-NVr0QzAgF8CBBDlrJO6KNhAARYAjDIAvMgA8AaWQQAHpBAATDGihYADtDABPPRAcA+ABSss1PMgDaqMigyHoAutQKSshiAJRarshYLFIyGlgARgBWWnIYkTiq6u6ExHA+JLzUAOQAUlgAFiBV0QA0rOnlpBTVNXAgEFUt7JxgPN3IVcpYA63iMckA9ABUyNIgshmZPqylEZg4LMTEHWj7ICxiyEsLQA)

Comment: Really cool. Why does this work though? Why doesn't it assume that the return type is `{ [P in (string | number | symbol)]: Person }`? I'm trying to understand it because I lack the necessary knowledge to have come up with this solution and I want to know what the gaps in my knowledge are.

Comment: The compiler uses heuristics when inferring generic type parameters from a call to a generic function.  In the case of something like `K extends PropertyKey`, where `PropertyKey` is an alias for `string | number | symbol`, it gives the compiler a hint that you would like it to infer `string` or `number` [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) where possible instead of widening it to `string` or `number`; see [ms/TS#10676](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676) for more details.